# Limit Custom Crawler to front end only

Tags: walker

I am using the following custom walker to hide the Login and Register pages from my navmenu created with wp_get_nav_menu_items.....

```
function wpse31748_exclude_menu_items( $items, $menu, $args ) {

// Iterate over the items to search and destroy
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
$registerpage = get_page_by_title( 'Register' );
$loginpage = get_page_by_title( 'Login' );
    foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
    if ( $item->object_id == $registerpage->ID ){
    unset( $items[$key] );
    }
    elseif ( $item->object_id == $loginpage->ID ){
    unset( $items[$key] );
    }
    else{}
}
return $items;
} else {
return $items;
}
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'wpse31748_exclude_menu_items', null, 3 );
```

It works fine but it is also affecting the menus page within the dashboard, is there a way to limit the crawler to only affect the front end?

Comment: You mean [`is_admin`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the `!is_admin()` so your code would be:

```
function wpse31748_exclude_menu_items( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    // Iterate over the items to search and destroy
    if ( !is_admin() && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $registerpage = get_page_by_title( 'Register' );
        $loginpage = get_page_by_title( 'Login' );
        foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
            if ( $item->object_id == $registerpage->ID ){
                unset( $items[$key] );
            }elseif ( $item->object_id == $loginpage->ID ){
                unset( $items[$key] );
            }
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'wpse31748_exclude_menu_items', null, 3 );
```

Comment: `is_admin() or add_filter( … );`

Comment: yes that's a nice one - it looks like I have been hardwired to use the logic inside the filters ;-)